# Why I see two Toolbars on my Activity when I am using ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, fragmentpageradapter

[image]I want to create ViewPager on a Activity to show my Fragments. But I also want to show my custom toolbar. But, I have two toolbars and ViewPager. One of them is my custom toolbar and the other one is default one. 
I declared theme like this  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarP015"
        android:background="@color/colorOfToolbar"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerP015">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="top" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".P000Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".P001CoordinatorLayout"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:parentActivityName=".P000Menu">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".P000Menu">
        </meta-data>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".P002FragmentReview"/>

    <activity android:name=".P003TwoFragmentCommunication"/>

    <activity android:name=".P004FragmentProgrammatically"/>

    <activity android:name=".P005FragmentProg2"/>

    <activity android:name=".P006Fragmentv4"/>

    <activity android:name=".P007Fonts"/>

    <activity android:name=".P008HATAScrollingMagic"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

    <activity android:name=".P009DrawerLayoutNew"/>

    <activity android:name=".P010DrawerLayoutFull"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

    <activity android:name=".P011LayoutProgrammatically"/>

    <activity android:name=".P012TabHostReview"/>

    <activity android:name=".P013TabHostNew"/>

    <activity android:name=".P014ViewPagerTransforms"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

    <activity android:name=".P015ViewPagerPagerTabStrip"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Post your `style.xml` and `manifest.xml` files.

Comment: I added style and manifest file.

Comment: Make sure that `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` is in correct place [`manifest.xml`]. Your `style.xml` and `layout` files are correct.

Comment: I checked it. But, it do not work as I aspected. The Activity name is P015ViewPagerPagerTabStrip .I also added one picture. Thank you for your interest

Comment: add this line requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); before setContentView()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `AppBarLayout` to:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarP015"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#6712FF" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

or remove `AppBarLayout` leaving `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Use NoActionBar theme in your activity with toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your Activity java class..

this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

I hope this work for you..

Comment: So You can remove this code from your .xml file

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarP015"
        android:background="@color/colorOfToolbar"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>